# Lotto Ticket Coverage From Algorithm Design Manual?

Tags: algorithm

I am reading the Algorithm Design Manual by Steven S. Skiena. I am in the first chapter reading about the lottery ticket problem. Skiena claims his first solution for the optimal number of tickets for a guaranteed win was incorrect. I do not understand how his next and final solution is correct?

In [figure 1.11](http://books.google.co.za/books?id=7XUSn0IKQEgC&lpg=PR1&dq=Algo%20Design%20Manual&pg=PA26#v=onepage&q=Algo%20Design%20Manual&f=false) he says: Guaranteeing a winning pair from `{1,2,3,4,5}` using only tickets `{1,2,3}` and `{1, 4, 5}` and there is a diagram. I am confused why the other numbers are not in there? For example, what if the winning numbers were `(3,4)`, `(2,4)`, `(2,5)`, `(3,5)`, etc...? You obviously cannot combine tickets together, so how can this be explained? In the lottery, if the winning numbers were 3 and 5, you must have one ticket that has a 3 and 5 in some order. Can someone please explain?

Comment: please provid full context, so I don't have to search this in the book...

Comment: @KarolyHorvath You can find the full chapter on books.google.com by looking for `"Guaranteeing a winning pair from"`... But it's too much hard for me :-) And I'm not even sure it's for SO

Comment: I think you have the right idea. In the author's own words (in the book) - "We hadn't modeled the problem correctly!".

Answer (score 22, accepted):

In the example

- n = 5 - the numbers from the psychic
- j = 3 - the number of winning numbers from n
- k = 3 - the number of slots on the ticket
- l = 2 - the number of matches needed to get a prized

What makes this case simple is the fact that all the numbers on the ticket must be between 1..5. This is because j=k, meaning the number of winning numbers falling between 1 and 5 matches the number of slots on the ticket.

So take the tickets {1, 2, 3} and {1, 4, 5}. That does indeed mean you're missing the match {3, 5} but if the numbers {3, 5} are on the ticket then the other number on the ticket must be from the set {1, 2, 4}. If its the 1 then the match 3 has been picket up by the first ticket, if its the 2 then then same, if its the 5 then the second ticket catches it.

Comment: Thanks @Colin Jack!

Another way to phrase it is that if the winning ticket contains the numbers {3, 5}, the winning ticket is actually one of the following: {1, 3, 5}, {2, 3, 5}, {4, 3, 5} - assuming that the psychic is right about those 5 numbers.

In the three winning cases (a) {1, 3, 5}, (b) {2, 3, 5}, (c) {4, 3, 5}, since only two numbers are needed to win the lottery, {1, 2, 3} is sufficient to win for winning cases (a) and (b), and {1, 4, 5} is sufficient to win for winning cases (a) and (c).

Comment: The issue with the original problem model is that while there are winning matches, the winning ticket actually generates more than 1 winning match. Hence a smaller number of tickets purchased can "cover" many winning tickets.

Comment: @colin-jack, still I couldn't get, it sounds to me that in n=5, j=3, k=3, l=2 we should simply break 5 numbers into triplets by avoiding duplicates so 1,2,3,4,5 becomes 1,2,3 and 1,4,5. If it is then that means to me having only 3 tickets solution for problem instance n=15, j=6, k=6, l=3: (a) 1,2,3,4,5,6, (b) 7,8,9,10,11,12 and (c) 13,14,15,x,y,z (for example 13,14,15,1,2,3). It seems to me I'm wrong. Can you please point me out?

Comment: skiena has meesing things.i spend 20 years of my life to find the minimum compinations for most of the systems .and i am teeling do not spend time reading bs.
first with the computer [power we have you must find the small groups like  6 numbers catch 3 get 2 . or 10 numbers catch 6 get 5 after you have everyhting until 14 numbers you can combine them and you get the minimum combination for each system up to 49 numbers

Comment: I understand why it works for the simplified case. But how about the original situation? I can't understand why the set given by the president can gurantee to win. It only has 5 elements.

Answer (score 2):

In figure 1.11 the number of slots on each ticket is 3. So there are 3 winning numbers. With two tickets {1,2,3} and {1,4,5}, you are guaranteed to have at least 2 out of the 3 winning numbers.